# When pushing a new object, a pointer to that object becomes garbage

Tags: c++

When I am pushing a reference to an object from a vector in a map the previous value in the reference vector becomes garbage, but the original object doesn't.

Here is the minimal code that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class foo
    {
        private:
            std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> _allObjs;
            std::vector<int*> _someObjs;

         public:
            void addObj(const std::string &name, int obj)
                {
                    _allObjs[name].push_back(obj);
                    _someObjs.push_back(&_allObjs[name].back());
                }

            void doStuff()
                {
                    for (auto &obj : _someObjs)
                        {
                            std::cout << *obj << std::endl;
                        }
                }

    };

int main()
    {
        foo test;
        test.addObj("test1", 5);
        test.addObj("test1", 6);

        test.addObj("test2", 7);
        test.addObj("test2", 8);

        test.doStuff();
    }

Expected Output
5
6
7
8

Actual Output
-572662307
6
-572662307
8
```

When debugging it I found the pointer becomes garbage as soon as I push the object to `_allObjs` in addObj. I have no idea what is causing this, so I can't be much help there. Thanks!

Comment: Adding an element to a vector can trigger a resize, which reallocates the internal storage, invalidating all existing pointers into the vector.

Comment: I am curious as to why you have `std::vector<int*>` instead of `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vector stores its data in a contiguous block of memory.

When you want to store more than it currently has capacity for, it will allocate a new, larger contiguous block of memory, and copy/move all the existing elements from the previous block of memory into the new one.

When you store pointers to your ints (`&_allObjs[name].back()`), you're storing the memory address of the `int` in **one of these** blocks of memory.

As soon as the vector grows to a size where it needs to create additional space, all these memory addresses will be pointing to deallocated addresses. Accessing them is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured it was something with the memory being reassigned because of the output

Answer (score 4):

Let us see what [this reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) says about inserting new objects to a vector:

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then **all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated**. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

So, when you add a new object, the previously stored pointers that refer to objects in that same vector may become invalid i.e. they no longer point to valid objects (unless you have made sure that capacity is not exceeded, which you didn't).

Answer (score 3):

The pointers in your

```
std::vector<int*> _someObjs;
```

aren't stable.

When you use

```
_allObjs[name].push_back(obj);
```

any addresses obtained earlier might be invalidated due to reallocation.

As written in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

As others have rightfully mentioned, adding items to a `vector` may be invalidating iterators and references on resizing of the `vector`.

If you want to quickly alleviate the situation with minimal code changes, change from a

`std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>`

to

`std::map<std::string, std::forward_list<int>>`
or
`std::map<std::string, std::list<int>>`

Since a `std::list / std::forward_list` does not invalidate iterators and references when resizing the list, then the above scenario should work (the only iterators that will be invalidated are ones pointing to items that you've removed from the list).

[Example using `std::list`](http://ideone.com/gxk0Yw)

Note that the drawback is that usage of linked list will not store items in contiguous memory unlike `std::vector`, and `std::list` takes up more memory.

Answer (score 1):

This: `_allObjs[name].push_back(obj);` (and the other `push_back`) potentially invalidates all iterators (and pointers) into the `vector`. You cannot assume *anything* about them afterwards.